# Why Client says CONNECTED whereas the SERVER does not say so in NODE JS?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

**Details Regarding SERVER and CLIENT.**

> *socket.io on server side (NODEJS)
>
>    socket.io-client on client side (also in NODEJS)*

Nothing is logged on the SERVER side, as the server never lets the client connect to itself.
Whereas on the CLIENT side I see this output:

> '*I HAVE CONNECTED*.'

**SERVER CODE:**

```
    var io = require('socket.io')(server); 

    io.use(function(socket, next){

        if (socket.handshake.query.user === "admin") {
            console.log("CALLED BEFORE CONNECTION........ :)");
            return next();
        }
        return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {  
        console.log('CLIENT HAS CONNECTED.');
    });
```

**CLIENT CODE:**

```
    var io = require('socket.io-client');

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000', { query: "user=admin11" });

    socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
        console.log('I HAVE CONNECTED.');
    });
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. With that exact code, `connect` on the client doesn't trigger (but `error` does, stating _"Authentication error"_, as expected).

Comment: Strange :/  
    "socket.io": "^2.0.1",  
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.1"  
I am using the above versions of sockets.  
And for node and npm:  
npm version: 3.10.10  
node version:  6.10.0

Comment: I tested with `2.0.2` for both, but I doubt it's related to that. What is `server`? (I lied a bit saying that I used the exact code, because instead of using a separate server I used `require('socket.io')(5000)`, perhaps that makes a difference)

Comment: Actually a strange thing occurred. Initially I had my server and client files in the same folder. But when I shifted them to another folder. It started working. I am not sure what exactly is the problem, when I put them in the same folder. :/

Comment: how can that possibly make the difference???? :/

Comment: I have no idea tbh.